# section not metioned in linker script

Tags: assembly, ld, protected-mode

What happens if I dont provide any information in my likner script for some section? Where it would be located? For example if I have following linker script

```
SECTIONS {
    .text = { *(.text) }
}
```

And in my `.S` file I have some another section `.section .mysection`. What would heppen with `mysection` section in the resulting `.o` file?
Would it even be loaded to the memory (protected mode)?

Also interesting what would heppen with `.data` and `.bss` sections.

**UPD**
Consider `.mysection` doesn't contain any information. It just looks like this.

```
.section .mysection
stack_bottom:
.skip 16384
stack_top
```

But it's still interesting if it contains something.

Comment: I believe that any sections that were not processed in your SECTIONS directive are still placed into the target in the order the sections first appeared while processing the input object files. If you don't have a SECTIONS directive at all in your script, all the sections will appear in the order they are first encountered in the input file objects.

Comment: @MichaelPetch but why when section `.mysection` is represented in `.o` file but it has no mark `loadable`. (I checked that with `objdump -s` and `objdump -h`). As I understand, it wont be loaded in the memory

Comment: Did `.mysection` have any data/code/definitions in it? If a section is encountered but has nothing declared in it, it will be discarded by default so wouldn't appear in the output.

Comment: @MichaelPetch updated my question to answer your question

Comment: In the update you show that the section is `.bootstrap_stack` but you talk about `.mysection`? Are you sure you actually have a `.mysection` section? Or did you mean `.bootstrap_stack` instead of `.mysection`? If you don't list a section and it has something in it (.bootstrap_stack has 16384 of data in it), it should appear in the output object. Either you are looking for the wrong section in objdump or you aren't processing the object file (with _LD_) that has the section you are interested in.

Comment: @MichaelPetch oh, sorry, yes, `mysection` is `bootstrap_stack`. Yes, it appears in `.o` file. But would it be loaded to the memory? It doesn't have `loadable` lable when I do `objdump -h`

Comment: @MichaelPetch it only has marks `CONTENTS, READONLY`

Comment: @MichaelPetch my is GNU assembler (as) but I think they have preatty the same dafaults. Thanks for help. Please, could you post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch sorry, I deleted my last comment to you, it was incorrect. From GAS documentation: `If no flags are specified, the default flags depend upon the section name. If the section name is not recognized, the default will be for the section to have none of the above flags: it will not be allocated in memory, nor writable, nor executable. The section will contain data.` (see `elf` section here https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html)

Comment: GAS has this in it's [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html) for ELF format: `If the section name is not recognized, the default will be for the section to have none of the above flags: it will not be allocated in memory, nor writable, nor executable. The section will contain data.`  . So the CONTENTS READONLY appear correct for that too.

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, but it says `not be allocated in memory`. So I think this mean that `.mysection` won't be loaded to the memory when file executed

Comment: @MichaelPetch ok. it's 3 am in my country so I'll go to sleep now, but I will really appreciate if you will explain it. Sorry if I answer it and accept a little later)

Comment: I'm more use to NASM. In order for your section to be loaded into memory (and not just appear in the file) you should mark it as .`#alloc, #write`. Try `.section .mysection, #alloc, #write` . Since you are using it for the stack you want it writable.